# WebBrowser add span tag

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can I add a `<span>` tag
After finding another span tag? Example have this tag:

```
<span data-offset-key="d5l2u-0-0">
<br data-text="true">
</span>

**Must look like this:**

<span data-offset-key="d5l2u-0-0">
   <span data-text="true">Hello stackoverflow</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Need more information, is this HTML code being generated by code behind?

Comment: Need to do a couple foreach find first Span **<span data-offset-key = "d5l2u-0-0">** After Span must include a tag in html with any word.

Comment: So I have this code generated **<span data-offset-key = "d5l2u-0-0">
<br data-text="true">
</ span>**

I need to automate and add any text using another tag: **<span data-text = "true"> Hello stackoverflow </ span>**

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery this way to substitute everything inside the span tag:

```
$(document).find('span').html('<span data-text="true">Hello stackoverflow</span>');
```

This will find the first span in the entire html. If you want to search inside some specific tag, like a div with id named "control" you can do this way:

```
$('#control').find('span').html('<span data-text="true">Hello stackoverflow</span>');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know how to do this in C #?

Comment: I'm don't know much about C#. Of course there is a easiest way to do, but I would try a regex expression. Search `(<span.*>)(.|\n)*(<\/span>)` and replace for `$1<span data-text="true">Hello stackoverflow<\/span>$3`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an HtmlHelper and putting it inside an HtmlHelperExtensions.cs file. This helper method uses the TagBuilder to create your custom embedded html span tag.

e.g.

```
public static MvcHtmlString SpanInSpan<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            string dataOffset = null,
            IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = (IDictionary<string, object>)null)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            var spanContent = metadata.Model.ToString();

            var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-text", "true");
            tagBuilder.InnerHtml = spanContent;

            var outerTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
            outerTagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            outerTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-offset-key", dataOffset);
            outerTagBuilder.InnerHtml = tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(outerTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
```

You can then use that inside your view to work with your view model

e.g.

```
@Html.SpanInSpan(x => x.PropertyName, "d5l2u-0-0")
```

The output after rendering this view is the following:

[image: Rendered View]

Comment: Thanks, but I could not use this feature in Windows Form. You know what I need to use in Win Form?